# 'Icon already includes gloss effects' doesn't work on iOS 6 compiled on xCode 5 with SDK 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

`Icon already includes gloss effects` doesn't work on iOS 6 compiled on xCode 5 with SDK 7. How to fix this issue? Image assets on the project are enabled.

Comment: try to remove icon from simulator clean the build and tried once again to run.

Comment: Clean doesn't help. Also I have checked the issue on the device.

Answer (score 75):

As iOS7 is not under NDA anymore, here is the answer :

> In Xcode 5 select Images.xcassets followed by your icon set. There is
>   a "pre-rendered icon" setting that removes the gloss

[image: assets settings]

Comment: For those who can't find the settings given in Kirualex answer, it's the Attributes Inspector in the Utilities page, which you can turn on at the upper right corner of your Xcode window.

Answer (score 18):

If you're not wanting to switch to the asset catalog, you can add the UIPrerenderedIcon key to your plist under the CFBundlePrimaryIcon dictionary (then clean):
[image: UIPrerenderedIcon]

Comment: This works for me. For a universal app, it is important to add UIPrerenderedIcon key under both "Icon files (iOS 5)" and "CFBundleIcons~ipad".

Comment: THESE are the droids you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @sc0rp10n, Xcode 5 has it listed in the plist as:

[image: Gloss effects pre-rendered in plist]